# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arraysss

Tags: angular, web, angular-material

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AnyArray } from 'mongoose';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-allpatients',
  templateUrl: './allpatients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./allpatients.component.css']
})
export class AllpatientsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  dataArray:any
  constructor(private ds:DataService){
    this.ds.getAllPatients().subscribe(data=>this.dataArray=data);
   
  }

  
 
ngOnInit(): void{

}
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////data.service.ts/////////////////////////

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {  }

  getAllPatients(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/patients')
  }



 
}
```

////////////////////////////my html////////////////////////////

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of dataArray ">
                            <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.age}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.phone</td>
                            <td>{{item.email}}</td>
```

The HTTP GET call response:

```
{"patients":[{"_id":"6374db3de99156199a548845","firstname":"yassine","lastname":"azaiez","email":"yassine@yahoo.fr","age":23,"phone":92810192,"__v":0},{"_id":"6375045dd2eeac54c6ecb89b","firstname":"malik","lastname":"karim","email":"malik@yahoo.com","age":12,"phone":999999,"__v":0},{"_id":"637607be05816c5a7829130d","firstname":"alex","lastname":"karima","email":"malik@yahoo.com","age":12,"phone":999999,"__v":0},{"_id":"637607d105816c5a7829130f","firstname":"alex","lastname":"karima","email":"malik@yahoo.com","age":12,"phone":999999,"__v":0},{"_id":"63768732bc19c7bb581a24af","firstname":"malik","lastname":"azaiez","email":"zk@hotmail.com","age":18,"phone":97829101,"__v":0}],"user":null}
```

what should I change in my code I don't know why it keeps giving me the same error

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` works for only iterable items like arrays so `dataArray`contains an object. Check what you receive when you call `http://localhost:3000/patients`

On the other hand, initialize dataArray with an empty array.

```
 dataArray:any = [];
```

***Update**:

According the http response you've added when you call to get patients, you receive an object in data and with the key "patients" you access the array of patients:

```
constructor(private ds:DataService){ 
this.ds.getAllPatients().subscribe(data=>this.dataArray=data.patients); 
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxqsqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hello Antonio so my http://localhost:3000/patients
contains all the informations firstname, lastname,age,phone,email

Comment: @MalikAzaiez I've just edited my answer

Comment: I wrote it like you told me but it gave me this error on patients.     Property 'patients' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: @MalikAzaiez It should work. Check the demo I've made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxqsqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts